# Комбобокс соединенный с Аксес

Tags: access, база-данных

Здравствуйте. В (Form4) находится DBgrid1, он выводит таблицу которая находится в Аксес (таблица учитель). Рядом стоит кнопка поиск, при нажатии на нее появляется другая форма  (Form9), которая совершает поиск по форме4(Form4).

В форме 9 (Form9)  находится два комбобокса и кнопка. Первый комбобокс соединен с аксес (то есть в комбобокс 1) и выводит столбец (fam_ychitel) из таблицы Учитель. Второй комбобокс тоже выводит столбец (name_ychitel) из той же таблицы (учитель). Кнопка ищет выбранные данные в комбобоксах.

Мне нужно сделать так: нажав на (комбобокс1) выбираю фамилию, а когда уже нажимаю на (комбобокс2), в выборочном списке появляется имя этой выбранной фамилии. Заранее Спасибо.

**Обновление**

Комбобокс1 соединен с аксес

```
procedure TForm9.ComboBox1DropDown(Sender: TObject); 
var i:integer;
begin
сombobox1.Items.Clear;
form4.ADOQUERY1.First;
for i:=1 to form4.ADOQUERY1.RecordCount do begin
Combobox1.Items.Add(form4.ADOQUERY1.fieldbyname('fam_ychitel').AsString);
form4.ADOQUERY1.Next;
end;
```

Комбобокс2 должен выводить имя. То есть когда я выбираю в комбобоксе1 фамилию сотрудника, нажав на комбобокс2 в выборочном списке должно появится имя этого сотрудника.

Comment: Если бы сюда можно было вставить картинку, я бы показал бы пример((

Comment: таблица называется --> (учитель); столбцы--> (id; fam_ychitel; name_ychitel;)